# Package X is not compatible with netstandard2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, .net-standard-2.0

I created a .NET Standard v2.0 project in Visual Studio 2017 v15.3.1 and I'm unable to install "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.0" package in it (by Nuget 4.3). Previously the .NET SDK and Runtime, both 2.0.0, were installed.

The errors I get follow this pattern:
"Package X is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)." (i.e. System.Reflection.TypeExtensions 4.1.0).

What could it be causing these errors?

EDIT: I'll show the exact warnings and errors with an example (there are too many).

Restoring packages for [.csproj path]...

Warning:

Package "System.Collections 4.3.0" was restored using ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" the project target framework ".NETStandard,Version=v2.0". This may cause compatibility problems.

...

Error:

Package Remotion.Linq 2.1.1 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package  Remotion.Linq 2.1.1 supports:

- net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
- net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
- net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
- netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0)
- portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)

...

Error restoring package. Reverting package changes for 'ClassLibrary1'.

Time elapsed: 00:00:02.4689637

========== Ended ==========

Comment: System.Reflection.TypeExtensions 4.1.0 won't work, it's too old. You will need version 4.4

Comment: Question editted with exact errors.
@DavidG Why is it taking packages not compatible with .net standard 2.0?

Comment: Well you have installed some weird packages here. What is `Remotion.Linq`? That's not part of the standard library.

Comment: It's actually a dependence from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, but it seems it takes an old version one.

Comment: Oops I missed that. Still odd though, have you tried creating a fresh project?

Comment: Yeah, same error. Strange that EntityFrameworkCore dependes on a version of a package (i.e. it accepts Remotion.Linq >= 2.1.1) but when that package is being restored, it shows the error "not compatible with .netstandard2.0".

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest versions of everything installed?

Comment: I think so... 

.NET Core Runtime 2.0
.NET Core SDK 2.0.


Pic: http://imgur.com/a/VYeu6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Issue solved installing, independently, newer versions for each of the packages' dependencies which were showing error, so that the big package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.0" gets installed at last.

Hope it helps.

Edited: It happened to me another time and tried a faster solution. The key was deleting Nuget's cache from the packages' manager configuration.

Comment: What worked for me was using the Package Manager console in Visual Studio to install instead of the Manager Packages tool for the project.

Comment: how di you delte nugets cache? was it by using dotnet nuget locals all –clear

Comment: what worked for me. removed reference to the project from the .csproj, and then clearing the nuget cache, then re-install library

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Clicking the "Clear all Nuget Caches" will resolve issue.

Comment: This helped with same situation in VS2019 & 22