# Package Plugin.MediaManager 1.2.2 is not compatible with netstandard2.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget, nuget-package, media-manager

I'm trying to add Plugin.MediaManager to my shared project but it gives me an error like this :
[image]

I've found this topic : [Package X is not compatible with netstandard2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784300/package-x-is-not-compatible-with-netstandard2-0) but this is not fixed my problem. I guess there is an mismatch between my project and this nuget package. What should I do to add this nuget package to my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the two following solution:

1. Migrate your xamarin project to the maui project. You can check the official document about [upgrading from Xamarin to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/). And you can add the reference of `Plugin.MediaManager 1.2.2` when your maui project's target framework is .net 7.0.
2. Install an old version of this package such as `Plugin.MediaManager 1.1.0` or older one which is compatible with netstandard2.0.

Comment: Thank you very much! I could add nuget package version Plugin.MediaManager 1.1.0